How to locate an element by Xpath/CSS selectors using Playwright
How to locate an element by Xpath/CSS selectors using Playwright TS/JS?
There are many locators in Playwright (in comparison to Selenium)
such as getByRole and getByText.
Is there any locator like getByCssSelector or getByXpath?

The question is too broad. Please ask something specific, practical and on-topic. You shouldn't be using CSS or XPath for 99% of selections anyway.

It's a technical question, not a discussion about locators stability. I'm kind of disagree, but I'm totally open to discuss this topic if you want in other platforms.

According to Playwright Docs about Locators

ou can use page.locator() to create a locator that takes a selector describing how to find an element in the page. Playwright supports CSS and XPath selectors, and auto-detects them if you omit css= or xpath= prefix.

// With Prefix
await page.locator('css=button').click(); // CssSelector
await page.locator('xpath=//button').click(); // Xpath

// Without Prefix
await page.locator('button').click(); // CssSelector
await page.locator('//button').click(); // Xpath

